# jquery store IDs in cookie as json or something

Tags: jquery, mysql, cookies

Baisicly what I am looking for is the best was to store data in either JSON or string formate, as I need to not show the same images again.

The way I am getting the images is by mysql_query ORDER BY RAND(); from there i want the jquery tp store the IDs either in a JSON formate or a string formate which can be done.

What I want to then to is save that is a $.cookies which i know how to do with jquery and send that list of ids to the mysql query and do a NOT IN( ids here ) which means that they will not show those listings.

If someone would tell me the best way to do it either store as json or string that would be great.

If storeing as a string I would need to replace the spaces with commas to allow the NOT IN function to work, I understand this and know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may as well store the values as a comma delimited string in the cookie since the ultimate target is the mySql NOT IN statement and will need to be converted anyway.